# django:column books_book.publication_date does not exist

Tags: python, django

I'm reading chapter 6 of django book:
http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html
And I've done whatever chapter 5 and 6 of this book told me and I checked my work and searched the error many times but I'm still having problem when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/books/book/ to add some book and save it, I get this error:

> ProgrammingError at /admin/books/book/
>
> column books_book.publication_date does not exist LINE 1:
>   ...books_book"."title", "books_book"."publisher_id", "books_boo...

And this is my models on models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

And this is on setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'books',
]
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
]
```

And this is on admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from django.contrib import admin
from books.models import Publisher, Author, Book

admin.site.register(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Book)
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you do db migration?

Comment: Yes I try python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate and python manage.py migrate --fake
and I get 
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, books, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

    books | auther

Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.

    Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel:
and I type no.

Comment: I tried typing yes too but it didn't make anything right.

Comment: run python manage.py showmigrations to make sure all migrations are applied

Answer (score -1):

```
Please correct your code like that:    

from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.books.models import Publisher, Author, Book

admin.site.register(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Book)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's just make some new errors when I try the python manage.py runserver:
ImportError: No module named books

Comment: books is you app name. your would have to 1st your project then you app name as book.